# How can I avoid the error "We can't display this page because your browser blocks cross-domain cookies"?

Tags: error, url, hyperlink

I have a LWC with conditional rendering.

When I use `lightning-formatted-url` component and click the link

```
<lightning-formatted-url value="#" label={title} onclick={handleLinkClick}>
</lightning-formatted-url>
```

I receive an error in Chrome

"We can't display this page because your browser blocks cross-domain cookies"

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

This looks really strange, but when I change the implementation to use simple anchor tag

```
<a href="#" onclick={handleLinkClick}>{title}</a>
```

no error is displayed